# a simple for loop in r to simulate a small set of data, print result works fine but setting a dataset creates a dataset with only 2 entries

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, simulation

I am trying to get a for loop to work. I have other iterations of this code but cannot for the life of me figure why this particular version is not working correctly.

```
result <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 101, ncol = 2))
colnames(result) <- c("i", "Ratio")

for (i in seq(0, 2, length.out = 101)){
p <- (1-pnorm(.5 + i))/(1-pnorm( i ))
    result[i, 1] <- i  
    result[i, 2] <- p
}

result

for (i in seq(0,2, length.out = 101)){
p <- (1-pnorm(.5 + i))/(1-pnorm( i ))
print (p)
}
```

The first block of code yields a dataframe with 2 entries and the rest NA. The second works. Changing the seq from (0,2) to (0,3) yields a dataframe with 3 entries, (0,4) with 4 entries and so forth.

I am really struggling to understand what is causing this behavior with my code.

Comment: your `i` values go: 0, 0.02, 0.04, etc... so when you do `result[i,1]`, there is no 0.02-nd row of a data.frame. Row indexes should be integer values.

Comment: @MrFlick wow, if it was a snake, it would have bit me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use

```
counter<-0
for (i in seq(0, 2, length.out = 101)){
 p <- (1-pnorm(.5 + i))/(1-pnorm( i ))
 result[counter, 1] <- i  
 result[counter, 2] <- p
 counter<-counter+1;
}

result
```